# Any decent weblogic tutorial?

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, weblogic11g

We are migrating an application from Tomcat to WebLogic. There are many things we just don't know about. Is there any decent tutorial out there?

We know about [this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839_01/index.htm) but I'd like to read about experiencies, and/or processed information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the topics you would like to see covered? J2EE is pretty wide and I don't think you'll find an all-in-one tutorial on Weblogic. Being a bit more specific (e.g. web deployment, jdbc, clustering) might help to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I'm late, but I'm going to share the two tutorials I'm following, since I would have found helpful to have those right away.

http://www.scribd.com/doc/6339325/Weblogic-Tutorial

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/WebLogic_Web_Tutorial

Comment: hi Eugenio...pdf from http://www.scribd.com/doc/6339325/Weblogic-Tutorial is not free ? Can you share if you have ? thank you

Answer (score 2):

WebLogic is a complex, enterprise-level product. I believe Oracle is making a pretty good attempt at explaining it in the intro doc: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839%5F01/web.1111/e13752/toc.htm. You can follow the links to get to the detailed documentation of the features that interest you.

If that's not to your liking, Amazon has books like e.g.
[http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Oracle-WebLogic-Server-Programmer/dp/0470484306](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470484306)

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on your app, but if you can deploy it in tomcat, I'd be surprised if you couldn't deploy it in WebLogic.

Having said that, I certainly hope you have a good reason for using WebLogic (and I hope that reason isn't "The sales guy said it's awesome"). In my admittedly limited experience with WebLogic, I've found it to be a huge pain to use and impossible to troubleshoot if something goes wrong (and it will go wrong).

On the other hand, I have lots of experience with Tomcat, which is dirt-simple to use and easy to troubleshoot (not that you need to troubleshoot, since it pretty much just works).

Comment: Please tell me why you would get more problems on Weblogic and why it would be harder to troubleshoot than Tomcat. Weblogic is well known to be a great application server and is used for lots of critical applications. Seriously, this is ridiculous FUD!

Comment: Wasn't meaning to spread FUD, sorry, but it is my experience. I have dealt with lots of organizations who deploy WebLogic, but don't have staff available to maintain it. This leads to problems that take a really long time to correct. WebLogic is so complex that you can't effectively isolate problems (the UI doesn't win any points either).

Unless your app really needs the huge complexity that WebLogic provides, I say you're better off with Tomcat. 

(I am making an assumption that the original poster does not need all those features, since he's using Tomcat now.)

Comment: I agree that Weblogic can do much more things and that it may thus requires more knowledge. But this doesn't change the troubleshooting process: thread dumps and log files are your best tools with both of them. And you won't get more problems with Weblogic than with Tomcat.